# C# working with button when button name is in a list

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have a few button created from a list, I now need to change one of the buttons image.
i am now trying to convert the string to a button.
How do i take the string and turn it in to a button that i can then work with ?

i have tried this:

`Button button = (Button)this.FindName("button_" + list[0].ToString());
 button.background = brush;`

i get an error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object  when i call button.background.

EDIT
this is how i have chosen to change the image of my button:

```
Uri resourceUri = new Uri("led_On.png", UriKind.Relative);
        StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(resourceUri);

        BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
        var brush = new ImageBrush();
        brush.ImageSource = temp;

        Button button = (Button)FindName("button_" + list[0].ToString());

        button.Background = brush;
```

i just cant grab the button with the name  button_list[0].

Comment: What is "this"? Is the button a child of this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to change the WPF Button `Image` on `Click` event (C#) is listed below:

*Listing 1. Changing Button Image on click (XAML)*

```
<Button Name ="button1" Click="button1_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Image x:Name="image1">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Source"  Value="Images/ContentImage.png" />
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

*Listing 2. C# code behind (button1.click event handler)*

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs a)
{
    Image _img= button1.Template.FindName("image1", button1) as Image;
    Style _imgStyle = new Style { TargetType = typeof(Image) };
     _imgStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Image.SourceProperty, new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyName;component//Images/ContentImage1.png"))));
    _img.Style = _imgStyle;
}
```

Pertinent to your code, it could be re-written in a simple form:

```
StreamResourceInfo _streamInfo = 
Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("led_On.png", UriKind.Relative));

button.Background = (new ImageBrush(){ImageSource=BitmapFrame.Create(_streamInfo.Stream)});
```

Just make sure that `button` object is not null (check this statement: `"button_" + list[0]` - may be just list[0]?)

Hope this may help.

Comment: thank you but i am just trying to take my list of strings and make them in to buttons that i can change a property on.

Comment: Please refer to my extended answer. Best regards,

Comment: So i guess that addresses my question, Why is the button null? i did a check and it was null.   i all so will use you simplified code to change my buttons image.  thanks

Comment: This should work provided that you specify the correct Button name (Button must exist prior to that check). Please mark the answer accepted and feel free to post other questions. Best regards,